# How to fix "key value error" in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I am trying to make a machine learning model for recognizing hand signs.
I am pretty new to machine learning and numpy. I am facing the following error

```
pixel0  pixel1  pixel2  pixel3  ...  pixel9212  pixel9213  pixel9214  

pixel9215
0     255     255     255     255  ...        255        255        255        255
0     255     255     255     255  ...        255        255        255        255
0     255     255     255     255  ...        255        255        255        255
0     255     255     255     255  ...        255        255        255        255
0     255     255     255     255  ...        255        255        255        255

[5 rows x 9216 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classification.py", line 12, in <module>
    y = np.array(train.pop('label'))
  File "/home/bing/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 809, in pop
    result = self[item]
  File "/home/bing/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/bing/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'label'
```

This is my classification.py

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 train = pd.read_csv("train60.csv")
 print(train.head())
 y = np.array(train.pop('label'))  # this is the error
```

I have posted the full trackback message
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes that is the error (Line 12). What is the output of line 11 ... print(train.head())? Will you paste it?

Comment: @Amit Sure I am pasting the whole output..

Comment: For the next time, keep in mind that your posted code should be **minimal**, and code that comes *after* the error is unnecessary and just creates clutter (see edited code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your train df does not have a column called 'label'. You can check for it by a simple addition to your script.

```py
if 'label' in train.columns:
    print("label column is present")
else:
    print("label column is not here. Popping 'label' will produce KeyError")
```

Also do you want to remove 'label' from the train df when you were using pop function? I am saying this because df.pop('MyColumnName') will return the 'MyColumnName' and drop it from the df. May be this is exactly what you want but I thought you should know. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html

Calling `pop` on a pandas DataFrame raises a KeyError if the column name you passed in was not found. This appears to be what's going on, but I can't tell without looking at your exact DataFrame. Double check to verify that the DataFrame `train` contains a column named "label."